# Wp-cli with wordpress plugin unit test

Tags: php, wordpress, testing

I am new in WordPress development.I created slideshow plugin .Now i want to do unit test .Through wp_cli can i generate automated test file? how? any one have video tutorial for that.or any nice example related to file upload tests.
[https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/plugin-unit-tests]

Answer (score 0):

There we have a tutorial by Pippin Williamson on unit testing on WordPress plugins.

https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-introduction/